# Printing a PDF using .net WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, vb.net, webbrowser-control

I want to use a .net WebBrowser to load nad print a PDF file.

But if i "navigate" to a PDF file, calling webbrowser.print doesn't fire. If I change navigate to eg. www.google.com, tehn it prints fine.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim web As New WebBrowser
        AddHandler web.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf web_DocumentCompleted
        web.Navigate("C:\my.pdf")
    End Sub


    Private Sub web_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
       Dim web As WebBrowser = DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
       web.ShowPrintDialog()
    End Sub             

End Class
```

Above code doesn't show the print dialog, but if I change to...

```
web.Navigate("www.google.com")
```

Then print dialog fires.

Why can't I show print dialog when loadin a PDF file?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue for the WebBrowser control. You can do it if you can get access to the underlying COM object according to  http://alexrazon.blogspot.com.au/2008/04/printing-pdf-using-webbrowser-control.html.